# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Accounts' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, api, entity-framework

When I try to create a new dialog and insert it in the database with 2 foreign relations entities Account and Customer who are in the database with both CustomerID 1 and AccountID 1 I get this error, I think it tries to also insert a new customer and a new account but thats not what I want....

My code looks like this:

```
    public Dialog CloseAndSaveDialog(Dialog dialog)
            {
                try
                {
                    DialogDTOC converter = new DialogDTOC();
                    AccountContainer accountContainer = new AccountContainer(_dbContext);
                    DialogDTO dialogDto = converter.ModelToDto(dialog);
                    dialogDto.Customer = new CustomerDTO() { CustomerID = 1 };
                    dialogDto.Account = new AccountDTO() { AccountID = 1 };
                    dialogDto.CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
                    dialogDto.Status = "Closed";
    
                    _dbContext.dialogs.Add(dialogDto);
                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    
                    return converter.DtoToModel(dialogDto);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }


    [Table(name: "Dialogs")]
        public class DialogDTO
        {
            [Key]
            public int DialogID { get; set; }
    
            [ForeignKey("AccountID")]
            public virtual AccountDTO Account { get; set; }
    
            [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
            public virtual CustomerDTO Customer { get; set; }
    
            [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
            public string Status { get; set; } = string.Empty;
            [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
            public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        }


[Table(name: "Customers")]
    public class CustomerDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    }

[Table(name: "Accounts")]
    public class AccountDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int AccountID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
        public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [ForeignKey("CompanyID")]
        public virtual CompanyDTO Company { get; set; } = new CompanyDTO();

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    }
```

Comment: `CustomerID = 1` and `AccountID = 1 ` should be removed. The database table has primary key column with autogenerated values. You can not assign explicit values to such columns. The database server will assign incremental value to these columns when a new row in inserted.

Comment: But how will I create a relation between de dialog and the one customer and the one account then?

Comment: question: are you trying to create new customer / account rows? or just use existing ones? if the latter: fetch them *from* the ORM first, i.e. `var account = ctx.Customers.Single(x => x.AccountId == 1);`

Comment: If you want to create a relationship with an already existing row in the database then you should not do `dialogDto.Customer = new CustomerDTO()`. the `new` is for telling ORM to create new row in the db table. You should retrieve existing CustomerDTO by ID, let say 1, first and then assign it to `dialogDto.Customer` by doing `dialogDto.Customer = existingCustomerDto;`

Comment: But the customer and the account already exists so i want to create a dialog and relate them so how does ORM knows that I want to relate it to account with account id 1 for example? Thanks for you guys help!

Comment: @MarcGravell i tried that but i dont want to get the whole account only the id form the database is that also possible? because i dont want to get the password and everything i just want to relate them with the id's

Comment: Oke so i have to fetch it first and then update it but how do i fetch the entity but not get all of its variables? like fetch the id so ORM knows i mean that one and dont get the password and email from the database?

Comment: Sorry i deleted someones comment accidentally...

Comment: @Bart by "password" you meant "salted password hash", right? Please? But: if you don't want to work with objects, there are ways to work directly at the database layer, in which case you don't need any fetch if you already know the ids - but: it looks like you're trying to use an ORM, so ... Let it do its job?